# Cross Domain AJAX POST / HTTPS / Header Authentication?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, https

I have to issues:

1) I've tried using JsonP, but can't get POSTing to work.  Essentially, I'm trying to authenticate with an API, passing a Base64-encoded namevaluepair in the header over HTTPS.

2) How do I pass this key/value in the header?  Any help would be appreciated!  Here is an example of what I want, though this obviously doesn't work:

```
               // where does this go?
               var headerString = 'user=' + encodeURIComponent(username + ':' + password);
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://anotherurl.on.another.server/LOGIN",
                    data: "I have no data, I'm logging in with header authentication",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {

                    },
                    error: function(data){

                  }
                });
```

Comment: jsonp uses GET request ... its sort of a hack

Comment: I was wondering why I was getting interesting console.log errors.  Makes sense with the "callback".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably through a server side proxy on your own domain.
See [this page](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Domain_Proxy) for tips.

This way you will be able to get the response from the other server

Comment: I don't want to have to mix PHP though; I can do that already :)

Answer (score 1):

add headers to ajax call:

```
var headerObj = {'user': encodeURIComponent(username + ':' + password)};
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "https://anotherurl.on.another.server/LOGIN",
     data: "I have no data, I'm logging in with header authentication",
     dataType: "json",
     headers: headerObj,
     success: function(data) {

     },
     error: function(data){

   }
});
```

Comment: The routes in the API do not except GET, only POST.

Comment: Then simply change `type: "GET"` to `type: "POST"`